# receiving arabic character from socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I have an application written in ANSI C, the application is receiving messages through a socket, messages contains mixed arabic and english characters, all arabic characters received as "?", I'm using the recv function, which stores the received data in a char*, I have tried to change it to wchar_t* but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

here's a code snippet that receive the message:

```
iReceiveLen = recv( g_iFIXSock, pszMsgData + iUsedLen, 1, 0 );
if( iReceiveLen > 0)
{
     // I do some extra coding here 
}
```

it's clear that I'm receiving character by character, however, I have changed the code to receive a block of 100 characters at a time, but still it doesn't work....

How can I receive the message correctly?

Comment: Yes you can, but you should show your code. Otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Sockets send and receive bytes. How are you encoding your text into bytes?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I have modified the question and I have added the piece of code which is responsible for receiving the data.

Comment: If you print the bytes you’re receiving as numbers (e.g. `%02x`), what shows up? That’ll be helpful in determining whether the encoding problem is with the sender or receiver.

Comment: @Ry-, Any arabic character appears as 3F as hexa decimal value.

Comment: OK, now do the same thing on the sender side.

Comment: @melpomene, unfortunately I can't, the sender is another application that I don't have any access to its code.......

Comment: But that's where your problem is, because the sender is literally sending you `?` characters.

Comment: @ManKeer If you're _receiving_ a stream of bytes (which is what `recv()` does), and printing them as a stream of bytes (code not shown) and seeing `?`/`0x3F` then it is the _other side_ that has already mangled the characters.

Comment: @melpomene, I agree with you, but when I visit the logs of that application, I see the message is written correctly without any mistaken character.

Comment: @ManKeer What the other app writes to its logs is not necessarily the same as what it sent on the network.

Comment: @ManKeer what the app writes to its log file, and what it transmits over the socket connection, are two completely different and unrelated things. Just because the characters appear correctly in the log file does not guarantee they are being sent over the socket correctly. And from the sounds of it, the app is NOT transmitting the characters correctly.